# This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have created an application in c++ using VS .Net. There is only the windows.h dependency in my application, all other header files are standard. But the problem is when I make the release of my application and run on other system it show the error dialog box,

"This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect".

Kindly help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read this (about WinSxS): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376307(VS.85).aspx

At some point, they invented a technology called WinSxS, and related "manifests". This make your app require DLLs with more strict version checking, which may be rather annoying.

You can hack it down by disabling embedded manifest, or link more libraries statically.